# Running C# MVC application at root of iis server with multiple application pools

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem with a site I am trying to prototype for my organization.  I am building a C# MVC site that will eventually be the front-end for all of our sites.  When I deploy it to the root of the server, it cuts off access to all our sub-sites that also run on MVC.  Our classic ASP sites work, but I think that's be cause the MVC routing engine can't handle those archaic sites anyway.

So, here's the layout of our application pool:

- root site (currently classic asp)
- sub-sites that have their own resource pools

I want to run my site at the root, and still be able to have the other applications run independently while they are upgraded/integrated with the root site.

When I try to access any sub-application directly, I get a 401.2 access denied error.  I have tried adding the sub-applications to a routes.IgnoreRoutes statement, and straight up adding a route for the sub-application.

Can anyone help me figure out if I can do this, and what I would need to do to make this work?  Do all the sub-applications have to be a part of the same project?  Any help/guidance you could provide would be immensely appreciated.

Edit:. All of the applications fall under one "site." Ourdomain.com/applications. I want mine to run at ourdomain.com, and still be able to run all of the applications.

Comment: Could you add virtual pathes to each application pool with own web.config ?

Comment: Each application is within its own path and pool with their own web.config already.  how would I implement that into my root application I'm developing?

Comment: It means you should set separate application pool for root site level too. Or am I something missed ? At least you could bind different port for root application.

Comment: oh.  That's how they are configured already.  Upon further testing, I have determined that it has something to do with the root web.config.

Comment: If your root application is bound with specific port and your sub-sites with different that should not intersecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.  I had to remove a bunch of stuff from the web.config that I deployed to the root of the site.  Bearing in mind that I have to deploy a **pre-compiled** application, here's what I removed:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Something else I had to do since our site uses active directory authentication is add the following to authorization:

```
<allow roles="DN\domain users"/>
```

The regular

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

was blocking all access to sub-applications without the roles being allowed at the root level web.config - regardless of the apps having their own web.config that specified their access rights.

Answer (score 1):

This solution for overriding user's access to specific folder but not for all of them in root application https://serverfault.com/questions/135825/disable-authentication-on-subfolders-of-an-asp-net-app-using-windows-authentic

Comment: Thank you for that.  I'll be sure to add this to my web config once i get back from vacation